# jax-b xml inverse reference with many to many relationship

Tags: java, xml, jpa, jaxb, java-ee-6

I have a few many to many relationships in my data model. I have been trying to use JAX=B to get XML representations of the data models, however I have read that for one to many relationships an:

```
@XmlInverseReference
```

is needed for the inverse side of the mapping. I believe this is for using different fetch types (ie. LAZY and EAGER). I am unsure of exactly how this annotation works. Does it use back pointers to ensure that data is not fetched when it is specified on certain fields? I also do not know if I need to annotate my many to many relationship with the above annotation or not.

Here is the user class that has a many to many relationship with itself, ie. a user can be friends with many other users. Should I annotate the getter with an @XmlInverseReference?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {

...

// bi-directional many-to-many association to User
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "friends", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "uid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "frienduId") })
    private List<User> friends;

/**
 * @return
 * 
 *         gets the list of users this user is friends with
 */
public List<User> getFriends() {
    return this.friends;
}

/**
 * @param friendsList
 * 
 *            sets the users friends list
 */
public void setFriends(List<User> friendsList) {
    this.friends = friendsList;
}
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

`@XmlInverseReference` is a EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) extension that enables you to map bidirectional relationships:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/03/moxys-xmlinversereference-is-now-truly.html

`@XmlInverseReference` serves two roles:

- During marshalling it prevents an infinite loop from occurring.  If a bidirectional relationship exists between `Foo` and `Bar`, it will marshal `Foo` then `Bar` and then it will stop before trying to marshal `Foo` again.
- During unmarshalling it will populate the back pointer.

Comment: Thank You for your clarification. I have been looking through your blog entries and they have been very helpful. One last question, is there a way to specify the relationship so that MOXy will not attempt to load relationships from the database unless specified, (i.e. lazy loading)? 

I have fears that my performance may suffer if I am attempting to marshal a class with many bi directional relationships.

Thank You again

Comment: @ReCoNciLiaTiOn - MOXy (or any JAXB implementation) is going to access every field/property that you have mapped.  JPA implementations typically make lazy loading part of the `get` method.  You may be able to get the behaviour you are looking for by mapping to the field using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

Comment: Can XmlInverseReference work for virtual mapping? As it is specified in https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/jpatoxml002.htm it seems FIELD access type is needed. XMLInverseReferenceMapping class seems using reflection to find the member field.

Comment: @JakeB did you ever manage to prevent the lazy relationships from being loaded? I've posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30163294/how-to-avoid-loading-lazy-bidirectional-relationships-with-moxy) because I couldn't achieve this (easily).