# How to avoid loading lazy bidirectional relationships with MOXy?

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

My question is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005039/jax-b-xml-inverse-reference-with-many-to-many-relationship#comment24618191_17031101) comment.

I'm mixing JPA and JAXB (MOXy) annotations on the same class, which works fine most of the time. As described in the linked thread, `@XmlInverseReference` prevents cycle exceptions when bidirectional relationships are marshalled. But in order to detect the cycle, MOXy has to inspect the back reference of the linked entity, which leads to extra SQL SELECTs if a lazy relation needs to be populated.

To illustrate the problem in detail, consider this made-up example:

```
@Entity
@Access( AccessType.FIELD )
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Phone {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "employeeID" )
    @XmlElement( name = "employee" )
    @XmlInverseReference( mappedBy = "phones" )
    private Employee employee;

    private String number;

    [...]
}


@Entity
@Access( AccessType.FIELD )
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Employee {
    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "employee" )
    @XmlElementWrapper( name = "phones" )
    @XmlElement( name = "phone" )
    @XmlInverseReference( mappedBy = "employee" )
    private List<Phone> phones;

    private String name;

    [...]
}
```

Now I'd run queries on `Phone`s with a JAX-RS method like this (using an underlying EJB):

```
@Inject
private PhoneService phoneService;

@GET
@Path( "/phones" )
public List<Phone> getPhonesByNumber( @QueryParam( "number" ) String number ) {
    List<Phone> result = phoneService.getPhonesByNumber( number );

    return result;
}
```

What happens is this: The JPQL query within the `PhoneService` EJB triggers an SQL SELECT on the `Phone` table (filtered by the number), and if I use a `JOIN FETCH` query, I can get the associated `Employee` with the same single SELECT statement.

When the JAX-RS method returns, the JAXB marshalling kicks in, which leads to an additional SQL SELECT: this one selects all `Phone`s whose `employeeID` points to the `Employee` who is associated with the originally requested `Phone`s. So the lazy relationship from `Employee` to `Phone` is resolved now, presumably because MOXy must be able to determine if the original `Phone` is contained in the collection.

I've tried using JPA property access and JAXB field access for the `phones` field, as suggested in the other thread, to no avail. I've also tried nulling out the `phones` field in the linked `Employee` instance after retrieving the result from the EJB, i.e. when my entities are detached already, but this led to an immediate SQL SELECT again (it seems like EclipseLink will do this whenever any manipulation is done to an `IndirectList`?). The only workaround solution I could find is to use MOXy `@XmlNamedObjectGraph`s with a subgraph that excludes the `phones` field. But that's not practical, especially if the involved entities have many attributes.

As I may need to query in the other direction too, e.g. employees by name with their associated phones, I can't just mark `phones` as `@XmlTransient`.

Does anyone have an elegant solution to suppress those extra SQL statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I collected some information about EclipseLink from [these](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg05258.html) [three](https://community.oracle.com/message/1708796) [threads](https://www.java.net/node/706426). Important bits:

> Detached Objects get the connection need to traverse the LAZY relationship from the EntityManagerFactory and will able able to use it as long as the EntityManagerFactory is open. The connection used in not the transactional one and when you want to use the entity in a transaction it will have to be properly merged.

> This is a special feature of TopLink's implementation where the detached instances created from non-tx reads still have access in their proxies to retrieve additional dettached instances. If the object was detached through serialization this would not be possible.

> If you would like TopLink Essentials to not process lazy relationships after the EM has closed I would recommend filing an enhancement request in GlassFish.

I couldn't find such an enhancement request though, let alone an implemented possibility to disable this feature (on a case-by-case basis).

There are five possible workarounds I could think of, each with its own drawbacks:

1. Just don't mix JAXB and JPA annotations on the same class: use a different set of additionatlly instantiated JAXB classes instead and perform explicit mapping between the two views. This could be a little expensive if lots of entities are returned from a query.
2. Like I mentioned in my question, use MOXy's (named) object graph feature to exclude (relationship) fields from being traversed.
3. Use a JAXB Marshaller.Listener to exclude all uninstantiated IndirectContainers.
4. Since serialization is supposed to break this EclipseLink feature for detached entities, serialize them before marshalling them. Seems awkward and even more expensive though.
5. This comes closest to emulating turning off the feature, but also looks hackish: access the wrapping `IndirectContainer` and its contained `ValueHolderInterface` and set them to `null`. Sample code:

(...)

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectContainer;

// entities must already be detached here, otherwise SQL UPDATEs will be triggered!
Employee e = phone.getEmployee();
IndirectContainer container = (IndirectContainer) e.getPhones();
container.setValueHolder( null );
e.setPhones( null );
```

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the easiest way to accomplish what you are trying is to detach all the entity classes before you pass them to a presentation layer like a JAX-RS rest api. You can even use the `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)` and [EntityManager.detach()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach(java.lang.Object)) to detach your phone class and subsequently detach your employee class or vice versa. This will ensure that during the marshaling of your entity, Jax-RS doesn't trigger any SELECT statements that you wouldn't normally want.

I always detach model entities before I pass them to the presentation layer so that they can interact with the model classes how they please without affecting performance or the database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately this doesn't work: like I said, my entities are already returned from the EJB in detached state; I think that is to be expected since I use the default persistence context and transaction scope, and my EJB is stateless. So the transaction finishes and with it the associated persistence context, detaching all the entities. I verified this with EntityManager.contains() on my entities. I even tried to do a manual EntityManager.clear() within the EJB method, but this changes nothing.

Comment: I don't quite understand it, but it looks to me like the `IndirectList` that EclipseLink uses internally for lazy relationships is still able to trigger SQL SELECTs after the transaction has already finished. Does that make any sense?

Comment: I just found a comment that supports my guess, [here](http://eclipse.1072660.n5.nabble.com/IndirectSet-IndirectList-relationship-may-cause-transaction-session-mix-up-td7336.html): "In general EclipseLink supports accessing LAZY relationships after the persistence context has been closed.  It does this using its non-transactional read connection pool."